# Page automatically reloads to home page after window.print()

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to print a modal in my page. But when i close the print page, my app automatically routes to home page.

I have not initiated any after print function.

```
export class NgbdModalContent_D {

constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

printElement(elem){

const printContent = elem ;
const WindowPrt = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=900,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WindowPrt.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WindowPrt.document.close();
WindowPrt.focus();
WindowPrt.print();
WindowPrt.close();
}

print(){
this.printElement(document.getElementById("printmodal"));
}

close() {
  this.activeModal.close();
  }  
 }
```

Comment: Can you post example on StackBlitz?

Comment: @Oen44 : I have added the same code in StackBlitz, [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tskmcj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) , it is working perfectly fine there but it is not working in my project, i have gone through everything but not sure what is missing..